# How to correctly write pattern rule in makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard src/kernel/*.c)
C_HEADERS = $(wildcard src/kernel/*.h)
C_SRC_NOT_DIR = $(notdir $(C_SOURCES))
C_OBJS = $(C_SRC_NOT_DIR:%.c=%.o)
OBJS = $(C_OBJS:%=$(OBJS_DIR)%)
BOOT_DIR = src/boot/
KERNEL_DIR = src/kernel/
OBJS_DIR = objs/
BIN_DIR = bin/
temp.o: $(OBJS)
     ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(C_SOURCES)%.c $(C_HEADERS)
    gcc -m32 -fno-pie -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS_DIR)*.o $(BIN_DIR)*.bin
```

This is my makefile. When I build I get:

```
make: *** No rule to build target "objs/k_print.o "required for" temp.o". Stop.
```

I suppose the problem is related to the pattern rule. Help?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(C_SOURCES)%.c $(C_HEADERS)
```

is not right. `C_SOURCES` is set to be the list of .c files. Perhaps you meant to use:

```
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(KERNEL_DIR)%.c $(C_HEADERS)
```